# Python: IOError with os.listdir - files exist but are not found

Tags: python, file, csv, for-loop, file-writing

I have a directory with a number of `csv` files I want to work with, all named `file_n.csv` with `n` ranging from 1 to 50. They contain `float` values, have a header, and have already been produced by another script. They are saved in a specific directory: `C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Loading_Maps`.

I want to open them all, one by one, to perform some calculations. To accomplish this, I wrote the following:

```
    directoryPath=raw_input('Directory for csv files: ')
    for file in os.listdir(directoryPath):
        if file.endswith(".csv"):
            filelabel=file[:-4]
            x=numpy.genfromtxt(file,delimiter=',')[:,2] 
            #do stuff
```

When asked, I input the `directoryPath` from the shell, assigning it `C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Loading_Maps`.

Then I get an error: `IOError: file_1.csv not found`.

**Why does this happen?** Why does it throw out an error, yet it successfully figures out the name of the first file in the assigned directory?

Alternative solutions to this would be very welcome. Thanks!

**EDIT**: The error stack for `csv` files with a unique `int` value (for testing purposes) following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564781/python-ioerror-with-os-listdir-files-exist-but-are-not-found/33564830#33564830).

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\france~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpcwygvc.py in <module>()
      5     if file.endswith(".csv"):
      6         filelabel=file[:-4]
----> 7         x=numpy.genfromtxt(os.path.join(directoryPath, file),delimiter=',')[0]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
import os
directoryPath=raw_input('Directory for csv files: ')
for file in os.listdir(directoryPath):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        filelabel=file[:-4]
        strPath = os.path.join(directoryPath, file)
        x=numpy.genfromtxt(strPath, delimiter=',')
        ans = x[:,2]
```

Comment: I tried this block with 3 `csv` files. They have `1`, `2`, `3`, respectively, as unique value. Then I get this error: `IndexError: too many indices for array`, which points to the `x` line. Then I changed the square brackets from `[:,2]` to `[0]` as my test files only have 1 value. But I get the same `error`... What is wrong?

Comment: Can you post the error stack ?

Comment: Yup. Check my edit. Thanks!

Comment: I have made changes in code. Try it out. And then again post the error stack. I think it will make more clear, whether the error is from numpy or from os module.

Comment: Same error, same `Traceback`. `IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\france~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpwcvahj.py in <module>()
      6         filelabel=file[:-4]
      7         strPath = os.path.join(directoryPath, file)
----> 8         x=numpy.genfromtxt(strPath, delimiter=',')[:,0]

IndexError: too many indices for array`

Comment: Ok, I think you have to check the file, in which parsing error is coming. May be it's not very well formatted or not have the format that numpy expects. Again I am modifying the code. Retry that

Comment: Yep, same error. This time it points to `ans=x[:,0]`. I replaced `2` with `0` since I only have 1 column in the test files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94425/discussion-between-user2393267-and-francesco-castellani).